# ZPL command how to reduce a barcode's size of the same ratio?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I would like to reduce my barcode's size but still be the same ratio like picture below.

From

[Original Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f76Sg.jpg)

To be

[Reduced Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w13zC.jpg)

Here is my ZPL code.

```
^XA
^FO50,20
^BY2,2,20
^BCN,,N,N,N,D
^FDZWW011601512345^FS
^XZ
```

Please help me how do I deal with it?

Thank you.

Comment: Label size is 2" x 1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This website is great for testing against: http://labelary.com/viewer.html.

Assuming you don't want the position to move it should just be changing

```
^BY2,2,20
```

to

```
^BY1,1,10
```

The API Reference guide can be found https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

Don't forget to take into consideration the print density, i.e. at 152 DPI you probably want something like

```
^FO150,20
^BY1,1,10
```

But at 600 DPI

```
^FO550,80
^BY4,1,40
```

---

EAN-13 Text Modifications

If you are using the the inbuilt EAN-13 text function i.e. `^BEN,40,Y,N` you can't modify the text. It is to a standard. You can however add your own text e.g.

```
^XA
^FO100,20
^BEN,40,N,N
^FD011601512345^FS
^CF0,48
^FO90,80^FD011601512345^FS
^XZ
```

`^BEN,40,N,N` The first `N` tells the printer to not generate the number underneath.

`^CF0,48` Is the select font function of the printer, its first parameter is a default printer font (can be found in the Standard Printer Fonts section of the link above). The second parameter is the font height. If needed there can be a 3rd parameter which alters the font width, though isn't needed.

`^FO90,80^FD011601512345^FS` Sets the field origin of the string starting at the location defined by `^FO`. `^FDXXXXXXXX^FS` draws the string.

Comment: Thank you @Chris Handy for your suggestion, Can I ask you something?

From the http://labelary.com/viewer.html , I can adjust the print density from the drop down.
 
But, how do I adjust the print density value as a code?

Comment: The print density is a feature of the printer itself. You can lower it by using the ^JM command but cannot explicitly set it to a value.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again (I really have no one to ask).

Can I ask you one more question?

I have to do another barcode type which is EAN-13 and I got a problem that is I cannot change font style and font size of EAN-13's interpretation line or human readable text where is under the EAN-13.

So, my question is How to do adjust the font size and font style?

Please help,
Thank you @Chris Handy

Comment: I have modified my answer, if it is sufficient please accept it.

Comment: That's cool, I can accept that.

Sorry for wasting your time.

Thank you so much for your help @Chris Handy.

Comment: It's not wasting! There isn't much about it the more reference that pops up about these things to easier they get. All the best